# Do stacked splitters split vertically in Dyson Sphere Program?

Tags: dyson-sphere-program

Both Splitters and Matrix Labs seem stackable initially to varying vertical levels, but the Splitters don't seem to work as we'd expect (like the Matrix Labs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct, Splitters unfortunately can't move material above/below, so Splitter stacking is only handy if running out of room on 0 altitude (ground level).

Comment: Note that while they don't innately split across stacked splitters, nothing is stopping you from connecting one to the other. When you use the second splitter type (the one with aligned exits, not in an X), you can loop around from one end to the other quite cleanly (and iteratively). So take the top south exit of the lower splitter, do a U turn, go up one level while moving North, do a U turn, connect to the bottom north entrance of the upper splitter.